# c++ leap year help please

Tags: c++

I am new at the forum, and trying to teach myself c++. I do have a question for you guys.My goal of this assignment is that will determine if a four-digit number is a leap year. I can not get it run with the years that are four digits in length. Would you please help me to get it run?

thank you

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
{
    int year (int year)
{
    if( (year%400==0 || year%100!=0) &&(year%4==0))
        cout<<year;
    else
        cout<<year;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

int main()

const int arraySize = 4; 
int yr [ arraySize ]; 
cout << "Enter " << arraySize << " four digits years:\n";
for ( int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++ )
    cin >> yr[ i ];
    cout << (yr)<<" is a leap year.\n" << endl;
}
```

This is really simple one that I've written, but I don't want it to run it for more than 4 digits, can you guys tell me how to do it?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

int year;
cout<<"Enter the year : ";
cin>>year;
if( (year % 400 == 0 || year % 100!=0) && ( year % 4 == 0))
    cout<<" is a leap year";
else        
    cout<<"is not a leap year";
cin.ignore();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I do have a question for you" I don't see it.

Comment: New at the forum? There's only one rule: This is not a forum.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What exactly is it you need help with? (You don't need an array of integers; a single integer can hold a four digit value by itself, and you can't do math on an entire array as a single value.)

Comment: There's nothing here that makes sense. Your `main` never calls your leap-year function; your leap-year function doesn't return a value; your leap-year function does input and output for no apparent reason; and `main` is trying to print the value of an *array*. Also, `int year (int year)` is a very poor decision.

Comment: Uh, the edit just added a misplaced brace and messed up the formatting. Always check the preview before hitting submit.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I agree with @Ken White. You don't need an array. One variable is all it needs. An `integer` one at that too. Just `mod 4` and you'll have your answer if the remainder is equal to 0 or greater than it. Looks like a really long program for something so simple. Please clear your English too. Thanks!

**Edit**

```
int y; 
cin y; 
if ((y%400 == 0 || y%100 != 0) && (y%4 == 0)) 
      cout<< y << " is a leap year";
```

Still don't know why you would need an array though.

Comment: I believe his logic is more detailed that what you suggest, its not just mod 4 ==0. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm

Comment: He needs an array because the intent (according to the UI) is to do batch processing.